# Importing multiple with some pattern in their names in R

Tags: r, lapply

We need to create a list, importing several `XLSX` files. These files have a pattern in their names, each one has the same first characters, but different numbers based on dates:

```
Opca202201
Opca202202
etc
```

Problm is: these files have multiple sheets, and the the name and the position of the sheet we need changes from file to file. They does have a pattern in the sheet name, such as:

```
Dados08777
Dados65423
etc
```

The word `Dados` always remain in the sheet.

We tried to use `lapply()`, `pattern()` and `read.xlsx()`, but we don't know how to find the exact sheet.

```
setwd("H:/Bases/Teste")
file.list <- list.files(pattern='*')
df.list <- lapply(file.list, read_excel)
df = bind_rows(df.list)
```

Could someone help us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `excel_sheets` function to get the sheet names:

```
setwd("H:/Bases/Teste")
file.list <- list.files(pattern='*')

## get the sheet names
sheets <- lapply(file.list, excel_sheets)
## filter down to sheets containing "Dados"
sheets <- lapply(sheets, stringr::str_subset, "Dados")

# iterate over file.list and sheets
df.list <- mapply(read_excel, path = file.list, sheet = sheets)

df = bind_rows(df.list)
```

As I've written it, this will probably cause errors if there is not exactly one "Dados" sheet per workbook. I'll leave it to you to handle those cases--a `for` loop might be easier than `lapply` if you need to be careful of that.